# Using child process to implement a logger function in c?

Tags: c, logging, fork, child-process

I have an  issue here with the following code. So in the logger.c file I am creating a logger child process which will keep looping waiting for reads. whenever running, I don't get anything it just waits.
I don't really see what I am doing wrong.
This logger file is basically logging the activity of the sensor_db.c file, i.e. logging a messageg whenever sensor_db is opened, a value is written to it and whenever it is closed.

sensor_db.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "config.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "logger.h"
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
// status 1: file opening error
// status 2: fork failure
// status 3: writing to db file failure
// status 4: file failed to close
// status 5: pipe creation failure

/* definition of global vars */


FILE* open_db(char *filename, bool append) {
    FILE *fp;
    if (append == true) {
        fp = fopen(filename, "a");
    } else {
        fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    }
    create_log_process();
    // Error handling for file opening
    if (fp == NULL) {
//        create_log_process();
        write_to_log_process("ERROR: could not open db file.");
        perror("Error occurred during file opening");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Communicate with the log process
    write_to_log_process("Data file opened.");
    return fp;
}


int insert_sensor(FILE * f, sensor_id_t id, sensor_value_t value, sensor_ts_t ts) {
    if (fprintf(f, "%d, %lf, %ld \n", id, value, ts) < 0) {
        write_to_log_process("ERROR: could not write to db file.");
        perror("Error writing to file");
        fclose(f);
        exit(3);
    }

    // Communicate with the log process
    write_to_log_process("Data inserted.");
    return 0;
}

int close_db(FILE * f) {
    if ( fclose(f) == EOF) {
        write_to_log_process("ERROR: could not close db file.");
        perror("Error closing file");
        exit(4);
    };
    // Communicate with the log process
    write_to_log_process("Data file closed.");
    end_log_process();

    return 0;
}
```

logger.c file:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000

// status 1: file opening error
// status 2: fork failure
// status 3: writing to log file failure
// status 4: file failed to close
// status 5: pipe creation failure
// status 6: writing to log file failure

/*global variables (for file opening + pipe)*/
FILE *fp;
int fd[2], pid;
int i = 0;

int create_log_process() {
    // log file opening
    fp = fopen("gateway.log", "a");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error occurred during log file opening");
        exit(1);
    }
    // creation of communication and child process
    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        perror("Error occurred during pipe creation");
        exit(5);
    };
    pid = fork();
    // error handle
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork failed");
        exit(2);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        close(fd[1]); // closing write_end.
        char received_message[BUFFER_SIZE];
        size_t message_length;
        while(read(fd[0], &message_length, sizeof(size_t)) > 0) {
            if ((read(fd[0], received_message, message_length)) > 0) {
                printf("test\n");
                printf("child process reads: %s \n", received_message);
                // timestamp creation.
                time_t timer;
                time(&timer);
                struct tm *timestamp_info;
                timestamp_info = localtime(&timer);
                char timestamp[20];
                strftime(timestamp, sizeof(timestamp), "%a %b %d %X %Y", timestamp_info);

                // writing message to log file.
                if (fprintf(fp, "%d - %s - %s\n", i++, timestamp, received_message) < 0) {
                    perror("Error occurred during writing to log file");
                    fclose(fp);
                };
                printf("test\n");
            }
        }
        close(fd[0]);
        fclose(fp);
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
//
//int write_to_log_process(char *msg) {
//    if (pid > 0) {
//        char message[BUFFER_SIZE];
//        strncpy(message, msg, sizeof(message) - 1);
//        message[sizeof(message) - 1] = '\0';  // Ensure null-termination
//        if (write(fd[1], message, strlen(message) + 1) == -1) {
//            perror("Error occurred during writing to pipe");
//            exit(3);
//        }
//            // opmerking!!! sizeof(msg) don't use, = size of the pointer! use buffer_size...
//            // with buffer_size you know for sure the nbytes you want to copy at most + is configurable.
//    }
//    return 0;
//}
int write_to_log_process(char *msg) {
    size_t msg_length = strlen(msg) + 1;
    write(fd[1], &msg_length, sizeof(size_t)); // writing the length to be read.
    if (write(fd[1], msg, strlen(msg) + 1) == -1) {  // writing the message as well.
        perror("Error occurred during writing to pipe");
        exit(3);
    }
    return 0;
}
// opmerking!!! sizeof(msg) don't use, = size of the pointer! use buffer_size...
// with buffer_size you know for sure the nbytes you want to copy at most + is configurable.

int end_log_process() {
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
    wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried debugging it but whenever I get to the read() function in the child process defined in the logger file the debugger stops running.

additionally.. this is the test code used:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <sys/types.h>

#include "sensor_db.h"
#include "logger.h"
#include "config.h"

int main()
{
    FILE *f = open_db("sensor_db.csv", true);

    sleep(1);
    sensor_id_t id = 1;
    sensor_value_t v = 0.001;
    sensor_ts_t ts = time(NULL);
    insert_sensor(f, id, v, ts);

    id = 2;
    v = 0.002;
    ts = time(NULL);
    insert_sensor(f, id, v, ts);
    id = 3;
    v = 0.003;
    ts = time(NULL);
    insert_sensor(f, id, v, ts);
    sleep(5);
    insert_sensor(f, 4, v, ts);
    close_db(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to null-terminate the received message. You're sending the null terminator in `write_to_log_process()`.

Comment: Why do you call `wait(NULL);` in `write_to_log_process()`? That waits for a child process to exit, but the child won't exit until the parent closes the pipe.

Comment: @Barmar this was a mistake. I fixed it indeed. now it prints child process reads: data file opened. and afterwards it is once again in a deadlock.Just removed the wait(NULL)

Comment: `sizeof(*msg)` is `sizeof(char)` which is `1`. So `buffer` is just 1 byte long.

Comment: @Barmar, fixed that thank you! unfortunately, I am only abe to get 1 message through after which it is once again in a deadlock still.

Comment: Strangely I am only getting 2 DAta inserts written to the log file whilst as you can see at the end in the main.c file there are 4 sensor data inserts. I would guess this is because the log process is too slow to acknowledge the other data insert message. Do you know how I can fix that perhaps? thanks a lot for the help! The other issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `message` variable in `write_to_log_process()`. `sizeof(*msg) == sizeof(char) == 1`, so `message` is only 1 byte long and not long enough to hold the copy of `msg`. As a result, you're writing out of bounds and causing undefined behavior.

It should have been `strlen(msg)+1` to make it the proper length. But there's no need to copy the message in the first place, just write directly from `msg`.

```
int write_to_log_process(char *msg) {
    if (write(fd[1], msg, strlen(msg) + 1) == -1) {  // +1 to include the null terminator
        // opmerking!!! sizeof(msg) don't use, = size of the pointer! use buffer_size...
        // with buffer_size you know for sure the nbytes you want to copy at most + is configurable.
        perror("Error occurred during writing to pipe");
        exit(3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strangely I am only getting 2 DAta inserts written to the log file whilst as you can see at the end in the main.c file there are 4 sensor data inserts. I would guess this is because the log process is too slow to acknowledge the other data insert message. Do you know how I can fix that perhaps? thanks a lot for the help! The other issue is fixed.

Comment: if I use a sleep function after every write_to_log_message() call, everything is printed. This means that the child processes is indeed too slow to acknowledge the other data inserted.

Comment: There's no guarantee that each `read()` will just read from a single `write()`. If the writing process is faster than the reading, it will read everything available in the pipe.

Comment: You need to create a way for it to detect message boundaries. You could send the length first, then the reader will read just that many bytes.

Comment: right! I see. Can you please tell me if you had something like this in mind? I do this for the writing function, i.e. I first give the length through the pipe
int write_to_log_process(char *msg) {
    size_t msg_length = strlen(msg) + 1;
    write(fd[1], &msg_length, sizeof(size_t)); // writing the length to be read.
    if (write(fd[1], msg, strlen(msg) + 1) == -1) {  // writing the message as well.
        perror("Error occurred during writing to pipe");
        exit(3);
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: then from the read end I read the message length first and then the message itself
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        close(fd[1]); // closing write_end.
        char received_message[BUFFER_SIZE];
        size_t message_length;
        while(read(fd[0], &message_length, sizeof(size_t)) > 0) {
            while ((read(fd[0], received_message, message_length)) > 0) {
                printf("test\n");
                printf("child process reads: %s \n", received_message);
                // timestamp creation.
                time_t timer;
            ...

Comment: You shouldn't have 2 loops. `while(true) { read message_length; read message; }`

Comment: **PLEASE DON'T MIND THE CODE** I FIGURED IT OUT.. I only wanted to ask one more question. So basically  I am now only reading the size of the message every single time which makes the log process able to process every message one at a time.. So to be sure that I comprehended this. The read will only read the size of message --> log message to file --> read size of next message --> log message to file and so forth, indepent of the 'speed' of the main/parent process? And at the end I just use `wait(NULL);` so that the parent process waits for the logging child process to finish up?

Comment: Correct, I only used the loop for reading the message_length and the actual message is read in an if conditional as `if (read() > 0) {the code};`

Comment: yes, that should work. The length you give to `read()` is a maximum, so it's possible for it to return less. But for a pipe that shouldn't happen as long as the sizes are less than PIPE_BUF.